# Prolog - Create a third sorted list from two already-sorted lists

Tags: sorting, prolog

I'm trying to obtain a third sorted list from two already sorted lists in Prolog.
The algorithm is the following:
1. Compare the heads of the two lists
1.1 if the first is less or equal to the second, insert it into the third list and then remove it from the first list.
1.2 else, insert the head of the second list into the third and remove it from the second.
2. repeat these steps until one list is empty.

In theory this should work, but there's something I'm missing.

Here's my code:

```
insSort([],[],[]).
insSort([],L,L).
insSort(L,[],L).
insSort([H1 | T1],[H2 | T2],L) :- H1 =< H2,
                                    append([H1],[],L1),
                                    insSort(T1,[H2 | T2],L1),L=L1,!.

insSort([H1 | T1],[H2 | T2],L) :- append([H2],[],L1),
                                    insSort(T2,[H1 | T1],L1),L=L1.
```

Comment: What is the result you get with the current code?

Comment: @Osiris, the result I was getting is `false`.

Comment: Do you know, how to get `true` ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstand how Prolog variables behave. After you assign a value to a variable (the term is “unify”), you can't ever change it. So when you assign the value of `[H1]` to `L1` (in a quite complicated way using `append`), another `insSort` can't use it to return the result. A way to fix your code would be like this:

```
insSort([],[],[]).
insSort([],L,L).
insSort(L,[],L).
insSort([H1 | T1],[H2 | T2],L) :- H1 =< H2,
                                  append([H1],L1,L),
                                  insSort(T1,[H2 | T2],L1),!.

insSort([H1 | T1],[H2 | T2],L) :- append([H2],L1,L),
                                  insSort(T2,[H1 | T1],L1).
```

This way, `L` is going to be `[H1|L1]`, where we know the value of `H1` and we're going to compute the value of `L1` in a while by calling `insSort` again.

Also, there is no need to use `append` here, something like `L = [H1|L1]` would suffice.

Comment: I do understand how variables behave in Prolog. What I was trying to do was similar to a factorial program (put the result in a new variable and then call the procedure recursively using that variable), but I guess it I need a little more practice. Your solution works perfectly. Thanks a million.